# Redis sentinel set up with spring boot

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-boot, redis

I have redis on 1 master and 2 slaves and on each server a sentinel process is running on port 26379

I want to know how to configure a sentinel as master in order to add for below in application.property file.

```
spring.redis.sentinel.master=
spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=
```

I have redis server 2.8.19 and spring boot 1.3.4, spring-data-redis 1.6.4 jars

Comment: This worked. Problem was with a later set up of redis replication, the name given by another person was something else than mymaster. So I enter the correct master name there it workes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Add support for Redis Sentinel Configuration GitHub request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/1337),

> Spring Data Redis 1.4.0 will introduce redis [Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) support.
>   Sentinels can be configured using `RedisSentinelConfiguration`. When
>   applied to `RedisConnectionFactory` the sentinel configuration will be
>   used to determine current master node an perform failover in case a
>   new master is elected.
>
> Added new config properties to `RedisProperties`:
>
> ```
> spring.redis.sentinel.master=mymaster #name of redis server
> spring.redis.sentinel.nodes=127.0.0.1:26379,127.0.0.1:26380 #deliminated list of sentinels.
> ```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: In this reply, mymaster is the name of redis master which has defined in sentinel.conf file in such line:
sentinel monitor mymaster <master-ip> <redis-port-on-master> <number-of-slaves>

Answer (score 0):

Recent Update

For future readers having the same problem and need to apply those configurations but having already upgraded to **Spring Boot 3.0**, then the configurations should be

```
spring.data.redis.sentinel.master= someMaster #name of master redis server
spring.data.redis.sentinel.nodes= some.domain.for.sentinel:26379, some.other.domain.for.other.sentinel:26379 #list of sentinels.
```